# ¿Cómo introducir un dato por teclado en POO Python y pasar ese dato como parámetro de un método?

Tags: python, poo, sql, input

Tengo un clase con sus atributos y todo eso, pero quiero que el usuario ingrese los datos por teclado debido a que la inmensa mayoría de programas es el usuario quien lo hace, pero me pregunto si es con el 'input' o hay algo especial siendo que es POO.

Comment: Hola Endersson , bienvenido a [es.so]. Realmente no hay nada especial en cuanto a la entrada estándar relacionado con la POO. Lo normal es usar input sin más.

Comment: Oh, muchas gracias por responder. Pensé que había alguna forma especial de hacerlo, pero gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo declarando la variable dentro de la función **init**
(la función constructora)
Te dejo un ejemplo:

def **init**(self):
self.valor1 = int(input("Ingrese primer valor:"))
self.valor2 = int(input("Ingrese segundo valor:"))